# Typed command incorrectly for wrong version - How do I correct?

Tags: 14.04, add-apt-repository

First time using Ubuntu Server
I added the following repositories following some directions not realizing that they were for the wrong version.  (Should have been trusty instead of saucy)

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe multiverse"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe multiverse"
```

I've redone it as trusty, but how do I remove the entry for saucy?

Answer (score 2):

From [`man add-apt-repository`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html):

```
-r, --remove Remove the specified repository
```

So:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe multiverse"
sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe multiverse"
```

Next time, just do

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

Since:

```
   REPOSITORY can  be  either  a  line  that  can  be  added  directly  to
   sources.list(5),  in the form ppa:<user>/<ppa-name> for adding Personal
   Package Archives, or a distribution component to enable.

   In the third form, the given distribution component will be enabled for
   all sources.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply with `sed`…

```
sudo sed '/saucy/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

The command above removes all Saucy repositories, but there is no reason to have Saucy repositories in your `sources.list`